# How to make iPhone Camera less sensitive to movement

Tags: iphone

I have made a "two screen app" in which the camera is divided into two sides left and right each of which can be captured independently and merged later.
The problem which iam facing is when ever user touches the capture button the camera moves a bit and captured image shakes so the user is unable to match the two halves.

Is there any way to make camera less sensitive to minor movements?
I am using imagepicker

Thanks

Comment: how about a count down? Taking picture in 3 .. 2 .. 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll your won image capture. Capture a larger image than necessary and stabilize the shown image using the gyro.

There is a great example of stabilizing the compass in much the same way here:

http://www.sundh.com/blog/2011/09/stabalize-compass-of-iphone-with-gyroscope/